# Are Azure credentials enough in an online Asp.net app or token is needed for CRM queries?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an account that is successfully connected to Azure and an App which is registered to Active directory. I also added all permissions as instructed so I published the app. Now I can login into this app with my Azure credentials online.

I also tested Postman with success adding all credentials and headers as per instructions here (learn.microsoft.com/.../setup-postman-environment) and I got response from CRM as expected, so this is working good.

As I am new to C# and Azure services I have some questions about next steps:

1. Do I need to obtain token in order to make CRM queries (GET, POST, DELETE...) towards "accounts" and "contacts"? Or is logging into app enough?
2. How can I make Controller to make all REST requests from #1? Can you give me some example?

Comment: Ideally you want to use the Dynamics SDK to connect to CRM using your org ID, region and service account details (Username/Password)

Comment: By "CRM Queries" do you mean running queries against a CRM product? Please clarify and add a tag.